# localstorage com react redux

Tags: react, localstorage, redux

bom dia, estou fazendo um teste com react-redux e localstorage ..ele funciona normal porem se eu der F5 na pagina ele nao recupera os dados que estavam sendo salvo no localstorage..alguém sabe o q pode ser?

localStorage.js

```js
export const loadState = () => {
    try {
      const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state')
      if (serializedState === null) {
        return undefined
      }
      return JSON.parse(serializedState)
    }
    catch (err) {
      return undefined
    }
  }
  
  export const saveState = (state) => {
    try {
      const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state)
      localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState)
    }
    catch (err) {
      // ignore
    }
  }
```

store.js

```js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react';
import rootReducer from './reduces';
import {saveState, loadState} from './localStorage';

const initalState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];
const sentryReduxEnhancer = Sentry.createReduxEnhancer (
  {
    // Optionally pass options
  }
);

const store = createStore (
  rootReducer,
  initalState,
  composeWithDevTools (applyMiddleware (...middleware), sentryReduxEnhancer),
  loadState ()
);

store.subscribe (() => {
  saveState ({
    teste: store.getState ().teste,
  });
});

export default store;
```

types.js

```js
export const GET_TESTE= 'GET_TESTE';
export const SALVA_TESTE= 'SALVA_TESTE';
export const TESTE_ERROR='TESTE_ERROR';
```

testeReducer.js

```js
import {GET_TESTE,SALVA_TESTE} from '../types';

const initialState = {
  teste: {},
  loading: true,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TESTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        teste: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
      case SALVA_TESTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        teste: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

testeAction.js

```js
import {GET_TESTE, TESTE_ERROR,SALVA_TESTE} from '../types';



export const getTeste = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
   var res = await localStorage.getItem("state").teste;
    dispatch ({
      type: GET_TESTE,
      payload: res,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch ({
      type: TESTE_ERROR,
      payload: console.log (e),
    });
    console.error (e);
    throw new Error (e);
  }
};

export const salvaTeste = (teste) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    console.log(teste)
    dispatch ({
      type: SALVA_TESTE,
      payload: teste,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch ({
      type: TESTE_ERROR,
      payload: console.log (e),
    });
    console.error (e);
    throw new Error (e);
  }
};
```

Comment: aonde inicial seu componente mestre? ele nele que deve ser feito o carregamento do que está no localStorage é assim, no seu código parece que não tem a parte do Provider então não consigo dizer.

Comment: esta incializando no store.js com loadState()

Comment: eu mexo com React nunca fiz assim, eu sempre faço um evento no init do componente principal aonde você viu esse código? que já inicial por essa função?

Comment: achei na net...vc fala fazer init onde esta o provider?

Comment: dou dispatch no inicio do componente que aparece primeiro

Comment: vc tem exemplo?

Comment: basicamente assim: `function counterReducer(state = { value: 0 }, {type, payload}) {` sabe essa parte do reducer então onde está o objeto `{value: 0}` é ai que eu faço.

Comment: Não deve colocar resolvido no título pois corrompe o princípio do site. A forma que tem de indicar que está resolvido é aceitar uma resposta como solução, clicando no certo que aparece à esquerda da mesma.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: mas eu expliquei e coloquei codigo q usei no teste...qual outra informacao vc fala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[createStore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) não admite 4 argumentos, mas apenas 3.

> 1. reducer (Function)
> 2. preloadedState (any)
> 3. enhancer (Function)

Reproduzi um exemplo aqui, mudando praticamente apenas isso: carregando o state a partir do localStorage e passando como o segundo argumento.

[image: Edit trusting-hermann-j2x7j]

Comment: isso mesmo...era so troca o initialstate pelo loadstate no createstore...obrigado